# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload add user name

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, ajax, blueimp

I need someone has experience with (blueimp fileupload jquery)

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

it suits my needs but I need to add the user session with every file insert to mysql db I've done a good deal of investigation, but, unfortunately, found nothing useful. In general, and The basic creation looks like this:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );
    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $query->bind_param(
            'sisss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->title,
            $file->description
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
    return $file;
}
```

How i can do this pls ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
    $index = null, $content_range = null) {
$file = parent::handle_file_upload(
    $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
);
if (empty($file->error)) {
    $mySession = $_SESSION['foo'];
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
        .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`, `session`)'
        .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $query->bind_param(
        'sissss',
        $file->name,
        $file->size,
        $file->type,
        $file->title,
        $file->description,
        $mySession
    );
    $query->execute();
    $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
}
return $file;
}
```

`$mySession` stores your Session parameter.

A new database field has been added to the `$sql` query.

The `bind_param` has been updated.

Hope this helps!